# What is wrong with this WHERE clause?

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a reason why this query doesn't work? The following query will work if I just exclude the WHERE clause. I need to know what is wrong with it. I know the given values of $key exists in the table, so why doesn't this work?

```
$q =   "SELECT * WHERE t1.project=$key
            FROM project_technologies AS t1
            JOIN languages AS t2
            ON t1.language = t2.key";
```

Table's have the following fields:

project_technologies
- key
- project
- language

languages
- key
- name

Comment: Mandatory comment to say "beware the evil monsters of SQL injection".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

WHERE goes after FROM/JOIN.

```
SELECT    * 
FROM      project_technologies AS t1
JOIN      languages AS t2
ON        t1.language = t2.key
WHERE     t1.project=$key
```

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT * FROM project_technologies AS t1
JOIN languages AS t2
  ON t1.language = t2.key
WHERE t1.project=$key
```

the `where` should be at the end (after JOINs)

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT *
            FROM project_technologies AS t1
            JOIN languages AS t2
            ON t1.language = t2.key
            WHERE t1.project=$key
```

Answer (score 3):

In SQL you write :

SELECT ... FROM tables ... WHERE conditions

You put the stuff in the wrong order...

Answer (score 3):

The WHERE clause comes after the FROM clause.

```
SELECT *
FROM project_technologies as t1
JOIN languages as t2
on t1.language = ts.key
WHERE t1.project = $key
```

Answer (score 3):

I think `WHERE` has to come after `FROM`.  Have you tried this?

```
$q =   "SELECT *
            FROM project_technologies AS t1
            JOIN languages AS t2
            ON t1.language = t2.key
            WHERE t1.project=$key";
```

Answer (score 1):

`FROM` comes before `WHERE` in a `SELECT` statement.

Answer (score 1):

```
"SELECT * FROM project_technologies AS t1  INNER JOIN languages AS t2 ON t1.language = t2.key WHERE t.project = '$key'";
```

Answer (score 0):

You should place your WHERE clause after your FROM clause.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this should be the right way to write it

```
"SELECT * FROM project_technologies AS t1 JOIN languages AS t2 ON t1.language = t2.key WHERE t1.project=$key";
```